# Convention on naming GUI variables in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, naming-conventions

As the title indicate, how should I name the variables that reference GUI elements.

```
buttonStartTest
startTestButton
btnStartTest
startTestBtn
```

or should I use `startTest`?

I like this one: `startTestButton`, but I don't know what the convention is, and what's a good way to name them. I know the Hungarian notation is discouraged, but on GUI it is "allowed".

I also wonder what is the prefered way to name variables referencing viewcontrollers? If you have a variable referencing a UINavigationController, I name them `myReferenceNVC`, should I just use `myReference`instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason to shorten `button` to `btn`, it clearly defies the verbose platform conventions and `button` is easier to read, so you can throw those out straight away.  Apple tends to append types rather than prepend them, so `fooButton` is preferable to `buttonFoo` - cf. `FooViewController`, `FooAppDelegate`, etc.

I started out not appending a type at all, but I found that instance variables that weren't UI elements often conflicted with names for UI elements, so I wouldn't recommend leaving `button` out altogether.

For more information, see [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) - Apple do have guidance for this.

Answer (score 1):

startTestButton or StartTestButton are ideal. And for the action method, use WasPressed:

```
@synthesize startTestButton;

...

- (IBAction) startTestButtonWasPressed: (id) sender
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just `startButtonTest`.  Instance variables should never start with capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended convention in *Beginning iPhone Development* (Jack Nutting, David Mark , Jeff LaMarche) is the following (in my words):

**Item Shortname + Item Description + Item Function**

So for example:

btnTestStart (-> btnTestStartDown for the IBAction)

lblHitCount

tableCountries (no function)

I've used this for 3 years without issues.

**That said:**

Anything works for your personal projects as long as you keep it consistent.

For bigger (collaborated) projects, stick to whatever the project lead lays out so that the project stays consistent.

Comment: For what it's worth, I hate reading code that shortens perfectly readable words like 'label' to 'lbl'.  It's more difficult to read, and I've been completely stumped on several occasions.  It's also much more difficult when not all of the developers have English as their first language.  Apple specifically recommend against shortening for a reason.

Comment: @Jim - Couldn't agree more. This isn't Wheel of Fortune 0x90 - you don't have to pay extra for vowels!

Comment: I hate abbreviated names, too.  Spell it out so your code is readable!   Beyond that, abbreviations undermine auto-completion and searches in that you have to learn a new set of spelling rules.   I nearly fired an engineer because they insisted on using some goofy abbreviated `m_BtnFoo` nonsense.  But they got better.